# How do I debug jquery AJAX calls?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have been working on trying to get AJAX to work with Jquery. My big issue so far has been that I don't really know how to figure out where I'm making a mistake. I don't really have a good way to debug AJAX calls.

I'm trying to set up an admin page where one of the functions I want to make is to change the permission set in my SQL database. I know that the .click function is being triggered, so I've narrowed that down, but I'm not sure where in the chain from AJAX call to SQL query its going wrong.

My .js code:

```
$('#ChangePermission').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'change_permission.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
        'user': document.GetElementById("user").value,
        'perm': document.GetElementById("perm").value
        }
    })
})
```

my .php handler:

```
<?php  
require_once(functions.php);

echo $_POST["user"];

try{
    $DBH = mysql_start();

    $STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO people ( username, permissions ) values (?, ?)");

    $STH->bindParam(1, $_POST["user"]);
    $STH->bindParam(2, $_POST["perm"]);

    $STH->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage;
}?>
```

Where the mysql_start is setup for the PDO function that I use successfully in my other SQL calls.

I have been researching and looking up tutorials for a few days now and I can't for the life of me figure out what's going wrong. Are there tools I can use to figure out where the error is occuring? I'm obviously interested in the answer to this specific issue, but I think my bigger issue here is that I have no idea where to start with debugging. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `require_once('functions.php');`?

Comment: See if this post helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991306/how-do-i-debug-a-jquery-ajax-request

Comment: first, does your `$_POST["user"]` really have a value?

Comment: Set up both a success and error handler for the ajax call and put logging in both.  You can then see what is happening.

Comment: **Use F12 in IE, Network Sniffer.** Or the network sniffer embedded in all browsers today. But you might actually be asking how do you track the outcome of an Ajax call, not debug it...

Comment: my functions.php file is the file where the mysql_start() function is defined.

Comment: @CodeAngry, I am using Ubuntu, so I don't have IE.

Comment: @user2619631 I said any browser (most have a network sniffer).

Comment: @Vainglory07, I am not sure. It kind of seems like the ajax call isn't being made at all. Shouldn't the ajax call create it?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Make your JQuery call more robust by adding success and error callbacks like this:

```
 $('#ChangePermission').click(function() {
     $.ajax({
         url: 'change_permission.php',
         type: 'POST',
         data: {
             'user': document.GetElementById("user").value,
             'perm': document.GetElementById("perm").value
         },
         success: function(result) { //we got the response
             alert('Successfully called');
         },
         error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
             alert('Exception:', exception);
         }
     })
 })
```

Comment: Hmmm, when I tried that, the .js file didn't even load. commenting out the success and error section makes it work again. Not sure what's going on with that.

Comment: throwing error in commenting is never recommended because it exposes UI error condition to every user. Better approach might be to use console.log with red font.

Comment: This throws an `Object object` error for me.. Not sure how to proceed

Answer (score 18):

Using pretty much any modern browser you need to learn the Network tab.
See this SO post about [How to debug AJAX calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21617685/2191572).

Answer (score 8):

You can use the "Network" tab in the browser (shift+ctrl+i) or [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/da/firefox/addon/firebug/).
But an even better solution - in my opinion - is in addition to use an external program such as [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to monitor/catch the traffic between browser and server.

Comment: This is the only correct answer. Don't add code to debug, use tools.

Comment: The [Chrome network tab](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network) is probably better than the Firebug equivalent these days.

Comment: Fiddler lets you modify Ajax requests before sending them. This is functionality I'm looking for. Ideally I'd like to do such a thing from within devtools. I need to add/modify parameters in the Ajax request. Firefox devtools offer that as "Edit and resend!". No luck in Chrome so far it seems.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using mozilla firefox than just install an add-on called `firebug`.

In your page press f12 in mozilla and firebug will open.

go for the `net` tab in firebug and in this tab go in the `xhr` tab.
and reload your page.
you will get 5 options in `xhr` `Params` `Headers` `Response` `HTML` and `Cookies`

so by going in `response` and `html` you can see which response you are getting after your ajax call.

Please let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 2):

Firebug as Firefox (FF) extension is currently (as per 01/2017) the only way to debug direct javascript responses from AJAX calls. Unfortunately, it's development is discontinued. And since Firefox 50, the Firebug also cannot be installed anymore due to compatability issues :-( They kind of emulated FF developer tools UI to recall Firebug UI in some way.

Unfortunatelly, FF native developer tools are not able to debug javascript returned directly by AJAX calls. Same applies to Chrome devel. tools.

I must have disabled upgrades of FF due to this issue, since I badly need to debug JS from XHR calls on current project. So not good news here - let's hope the feature to debug direct JS responses will be incorporated into FF/Chrome developer tools soon.

Answer (score 2):

### 2020 answer with Chrome dev tools

**To debug any XHR request**:

1. Open Chrome DEV tools (F12)
2. Right-click your Ajax url in the console

[image: Chrome console Ajax request]

for a **GET request**:

- click *Open in new tab*

for a **POST request**:

1. click *Reveal in Network panel*
2. In the *Network panel*:

   1. click on your request
   2. click on the *response* tab to see the details
      [image: Chrome Network panel's response tab]

Answer (score 0):

you can use success function, once see this [jquery.ajax settings](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
 $('#ChangePermission').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'change_permission.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
        'user': document.GetElementById("user").value,
        'perm': document.GetElementById("perm").value
        }
       success:function(result)//we got the response
       {
        //you can try to write alert(result) to see what is the response,this result variable will contains what you prints in the php page
       }
    })
})
```

we can also have error() function

hope this helps you

Comment: I tried using the success function and it didn't seem to trigger, so I  guess its an issue with the AJAX call. Is there any way to get information about why it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Install Firebig to see where your error is happening.  You could also set up a callback in your ajax call to return your error messages from your PHP.  Eg.

```
error: function(e){
     alert(e);
     }
```

Comment: I downloaded firebug but I'm not sure where exactly to look to catch the error. all of the tabs seem to be loaded and nothing changes when I click the button (although I can make an alert window pop up in the .click function). additionally, when I add either the error or the success  functions, the .js file doesn't even load. I'm quite perplexed at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this after jQuery loads and before your code.

```
$(window).ajaxComplete(function () {console.log('Ajax Complete'); });
$(window).ajaxError(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {console.log('Ajax Error');
    console.log('data: ' + data);
    console.log('textStatus: ' + textStatus);
        console.log('jqXHR: ' + jqXHR); });
$(window).ajaxSend(function () {console.log('Ajax Send'); });
$(window).ajaxStart(function () {console.log('Ajax Start'); });
$(window).ajaxStop(function () {console.log('Ajax Stop'); });
$(window).ajaxSuccess(function () {console.log('Ajax Success'); });
```

Comment: so if nothing is triggered, does that mean that the ajax call isn't being called at all? I added an alert() to the .click function, so I know that's being triggered. I didn't get anything with your code put in there though..

Comment: I think so.
This should display every step of a jQuery ajax call in your browsers console.

Answer (score 0):

here is what I would do in order to debug and get the php errors into javascript console.log after an ajax call:

```
    $('#ChangePermission').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'change_permission.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'user': document.GetElementById("user").value,
            'perm': document.GetElementById("perm").value
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);  
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

on the php side I would start by asking for all error returned to string concat and echo as a json encoded response that will includes php error messages as well if any.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once(functions . php);
$result = "true";
$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO people ( username, permissions ) values (?, ?)");

if (isset($_POST["user"]) && isset($_POST["perm"])) {
    $STH->bindParam(1, $_POST["user"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $STH->bindParam(2, $_POST["perm"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
try {
    $STH->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $result .= $e->getMessage;
}
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```