# Pass string through Jquery and ajax to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've been struggeling with this problem for a while now and I still can't understand why it's not working. I've tried multiple possibilites but none of them worked, so can someone please help me with how to pass `var superstr = $( "#savelyric" ).text();` through Ajax and into my database? This is what I've been experimenting with:

```
        function saveinPHP() {
        //alert("Came here");
        var lyr = $( "#savelyric" ).text();
        var superstr = { lyricsave:lyr }
        //var superstr = 'lol';
        //var hashString = "lol";
        //var data = { yoururl:'hmm'}
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/sendlyrics.php",
        data: superstr,
        success:  function(data){
            alert("***DATA***"+data+"***MSG***");
            alert("Settings has been updated successfully." + data + "~~~" + hashString);
            //window.location.reload(true);
        }
    });
    }
```

And as you can see, I've tried with multiple ways of doing it, but it just never works. I don't understand how on earth you do this. And the PHP file goes like this:

```
<?php 
include ('db_connect.php');

$data = $_POST['data'];

$query = "UPDATE song SET time='".$data."' WHERE id='1'";
mysqli_query($query);

?>
```

And yes, I'm fully aware that my database is vulnerable for SQL injections, and I will fix that as soon as I get this working.

This is what I've tried, but I can do things completely different if you think that is necessary.

Right now I got the JS:

```
function saveinPHP() {
        var superstr = $( "#savelyric" ).text();
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/sendlyrics.php",
        data: {superstr: superstr},
        success:  function(data){
            alert("***DATA***"+data+"***MSG***");
            alert("Settings has been updated successfully." + data + "~~~");
            //window.location.reload(true);
        }
    });
```

And PHP

```
<?php 
include ('db_connect.php');

$data = $_POST['superstr'];

$query = "UPDATE song SET lyrtime='".$data."' WHERE id='1'";
mysqli_query($query);
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150130/ajax-and-php-to-enter-multiple-forms-input-to-database/20150474#20150474

Comment: `$data = $_POST['data'];` should be `$data = $_POST['lyricsave'];`

Comment: Why do you expect that your data will be in `$_POST['data']`? The object you post is `superstr` so it only has the key `lyricsave` . Did you already look  if anything is inside of `$_POST` by using `var_dump` ?

Comment: Few ideas, there is fail function in JQuery, so you cansee if your query fail. Do var_dump of your variables. And MonkeyZeus, looks right, you have an error in your data.

Comment: ajax isn't some mystical new technology, what you're doing at the moment is no different than a `<form method="POST">` with a single input `<input type="text" name="lyricsave" value="somevalue">`. Given that, how should you retrieve the value posted with a name "lyricsave" in php?

Comment: Additionally, what kind of element is `"#savelyric"`? does it have `.text()`? or does it have a value.

Comment: Save lyric is a div with content, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass `var superstr = $( "#savelyric" ).text();` as your question states, but in your code you are actually assigning:

```
var superstr = { lyricsave:lyr }
```

Change it to:

```
var superstr = $( "#savelyric" ).text();
```

UPDATE (per Kevin B's comment)

You also need to change the following:

```
data: {superstr: superstr},
```

and in your PHP:

```
$data = $_POST['superstr'];
```

Also, why are you tring to set it to the `time` column? I have not seen your tables, but a wild guess will tell me that time is a different datatype (TIMESTAMP/DATETIME maybe?) and is rejecting your data. Don't you want to set it to a column named `data` or `lyrics` or anything which contains text?

Comment: My DB is set up with the song id, name, artist, lyrics and time. The time is "longtext", because the time is not "date-time", it's the time in the song a line of lyric will highlight :)

Comment: `var superstr = $( "#savelyric" ).text();` won't work, the data option needs key/value pairs or a paramstring. What he was already doing should have worked, assuming he reads the proper form value in php and .text() is getting the correct value.

Comment: If you only change this in the code, then just a string is send as the body of the post. This will not appear in `$_POST` as it is not a `key` `value` pair then.

Comment: So I've changed it as you said in your post, and I've changed the name to "lyrtime" in the database, because it might have been something fishy with that name, but it still don't work...

Comment: I don't get the $data value in the success function either

Comment: @Yani Yes I did, but I don't get it to work. I can update with the things I got now...

Comment: what errors are you receiving?? looks legit to me, (1) do var_dump (2) check your browser console for error (3) debug the response from the Ajax using your browser network tools. is the URL even correcT?

Comment: Currently I'm not getting any errors at all, I have no idea how to do a var_dump, under the response section under the sendlyrics.php inside the network section it says: This request has no response data available, and I'm also wondering why my success function is not working :P

Comment: You need to learn how to debug both your client and server side scripts. If you are not listening for errors, you are not always going to see them. Ajax only return the success event if it was successful. Add an error event handler http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991306/how-do-i-debug-a-jquery-ajax-request

Answer (score 0):

Only change this line:

```
var superstr = { lyricsave:lyr }
```

with

```
var superstr = { data:lyr }
```