# How I can POST data to a php file with ajax jQuery and save this in a json file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

hi i have a problem with my application. I use xampp for testing my application. I have two folders in htdocs:

folder client: here is the index.html and a underfolder with the js file.

folder server: here i have a server.php file and data.json file.

I get from a friend the code and I look why it not work but i not know what is wrong.

the application must create a user and send this about jQuery Ajax to the php file and this save the data in the json file.

If I click on the Button nothing happens :(

here is the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" id="add">Mitarbeiter hinzufügen</button>
    <div id="TableContent"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Fill table with data from server on first load
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../server/server.php",
        data: {
            method: "all"
        },
        success: function(content) {
            // Create table content from server data
            var table = $.makeTable($.parseJSON(content));
            // Append table data to table element in index.html
            $(table).appendTo("#TableContent");
        }
    });

    // Add user
    $('#add').on('click', function(){

        alert("Ein neuer Benutzer wird erstellt");

        console.log('add user');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../server/server.php",
            data: {
                vorname: "Wowa",
                nachname: "Tarasov"
            },
            success: function(content) {
                alert(content);
            }
        });
    });

    // Delete user
    $(document).on("click", "button.remove" , function() {
        // Send DELETE request to server
        // Id of a user
        console.log($(this).attr('value'));
        console.log('delete');

        $.ajax({
            type: "DELETE",
            url: "../server/server.php",
            data: {
                method: "all"
            },
            success: function(content) {
                // content is a response from server
                // Don't forgive to update the table after adding of a user
            }
        });
    });

    // Function to generate a table from a json array
    // It will not work, if you pass an object to it
    $.makeTable = function (mydata) {
        var table = $('<table border=1>');
        var tblHeader = "<tr>";
        for (var k in mydata[0]) tblHeader += "<th>" + k + "</th>";
        tblHeader += "<th>Aktionen</th>"
        tblHeader += "</tr>";
        $(tblHeader).appendTo(table);
        $.each(mydata, function (index, value) {
            var TableRow = "<tr>";
            var idx = value.id;
            $.each(value, function (key, val) {
                TableRow += "<td>" + val + "</td>";
            });
            TableRow += '<td><button class="remove" value=' + idx + '>Delete</button></td>';
            TableRow += "</tr>";
            $(table).append(TableRow);
        });
        return ($(table));
    };
});
```

and here is the php:

```
<?php

class Request
{
    public $url_elements;
    public $methode;
    public $parameters;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->methode = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        if(isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])) $this->url_elements = explode('/', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
        else $this->url_elements = array();
        // get GET/DELETE or POST/PUT parameters
        $parameters = array();
        if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {  // get GET/DELETE parameters
            parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $parameters);
        }
        $body = file_get_contents("php://input"); // get POST/PUT request body
        parse_str($body, $postvars);
        foreach ($postvars as $field => $value) {
            $parameters[$field] = $value; // overwrite GET/DELETE parameteres
        }

        $this->parameters = $parameters;
    }
}

/**
 * Class RequestHandler handles GET, POST, PUT and DELETE HTTP-requests from clients
 */
class RequestHandler
{
    /**
     * Read method
     */
    public function getAction($request)
    {
        $data = $request->parameters;


        switch ($request->parameters['method']) {
            case 'all':

                $person1 = new stdClass;
                $person1->Id = 1;
                $person1->Vorname = "Max";
                $person1->Nachname = "Mustermann";
                $person1->Geburtstag = "11.11.1980";
                $person1->Abteilung = "Personal";

                $person2 = new stdClass;
                $person2->Id = 2;
                $person2->Vorname = "Sabine";
                $person2->Nachname = "Musterfrau";
                $person2->Geburtstag = "05.12.1989";
                $person2->Abteilung = "Finanzen";

                // Add person in array
                $persons = array();
                array_push($persons, $person1);
                array_push($persons, $person2);

                // Encode array to json string and return to client
                return json_encode($persons);
                break;
            case 'single_user':
                break;
            default: // do nothing, this is not a supported action
                break;
        }
        return json_encode($data);
    }

    /**
     * Delete method
     */
    public function deleteAction($request)
    {
        $data = $request->parameters;
        return json_encode($data);
    }

    /**
     * Create method
     */
    public function postAction($request)
    {
        $data = $request->parameters;
        return json_encode($data);
    }

    /**
     * Update method
     */
    public function putAction($request)
    {
        $data = $request->parameters;
        return json_encode($data);
    }
}

$request = new Request();
$handler = new RequestHandler();
$action = strtolower($request->methode) . 'Action';
$result = $handler->$action($request);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: You mean your  `alert()` doesn't fire?
Have you any error in your console?
Those questions maybe appear to be dump, but according to this http://jsfiddle.net/sorzd61p/ your code (except for the ajax call on jsfiddle)

Comment: have you tried calling this script without ajax, so you get the proper php error message?

Comment: how i said it is the code of a firend and he want to use ajax ...i look but i dont found a error :(

Comment: make a basic form and use post to call the php script. then you will see the php error message.

Comment: Please specify the exact url you're using in your browser to access the files.

Comment: http://localhost/client/index.html ?

Comment: You said us that your click event doesn't work, but does your first ajax call return something? If no look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991306/how-do-i-debug-a-jquery-ajax-request