# Pass variables to URL in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the below ajax call in which I am trying to post the registration data directly to URL, but is there anyway I can store those variables and then pass it into the URL. Please help thank you in advance.

You can see the Script.js in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XmsAh20ZjGwtSVFIoaqK?p=preview)

jquery:

```
$(function() {

    /* Registration form for the website */
    /* validation */
    $("#register-form").validate({
        rules: {
            firstName: {
                required: true
            },
            lastName: {
                required: true
            },
            userName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8,
                maxlength: 15
            },
            cpassword: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: '#password'
            },
        },
        messages: {
            userName: "please enter a valid user name",
            password: {
                required: "please provide a password",
                minlength: "password at least have 8 characters"
            },
            email: "please enter a valid email address",
            cpassword: {
                required: "please retype your password",
                equalTo: "password doesn't match !"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: submitForm
    });
    /* validation */

    /* form submit */
    function submitForm() {
        var data = $("#register-form").serialize();
        // var data={
        //  firstName: $('#firstName').val(),
        // }

        $.ajax({

            url: 'http://localhost:8000?userName=&password=&firstName=&lastName=&email=',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,

            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#error").fadeOut();
                $("#btn-submit").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span> &nbsp; sending ...');
            },

            success: function(data) {
                if (data === 0) {

                    $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function() {


                        $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; Sorry email already taken !</div>');

                        $("#btn-submit").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Create Account');

                    });

                } else if (data == 1) {

                    $("#btn-submit").html('<img src="btn-ajax-loader.gif" /> &nbsp; Signing Up ...');

                } else {

                    $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function() {

                        $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; ' + data + ' !</div>');

                        $("#btn-submit").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Create Account');

                    });

                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if data is passed in ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766927/how-to-check-if-data-is-passed-in-ajax)

Comment: If you like to put the variables into the URL then use type `GET` request.

Comment: @Leo it is a duplicate I agree but this is different problem I am having. I am able to see the data but its not being passed to the URL correctly, for some reason there is a 'comma' leading to all the inputs. And I think this is because I have hard coded it to the URL itself instead of storing each individual component and then pass it to URL. Could you please help with an example.

Comment: Why do you use POST if you try to insert the variables into the url?

Comment: Juste change this two lines
            url: 'http://localhost:8000?userName=&password=&firstName=&lastName=&email=',
            type: 'POST',
by
            url: 'http://localhost:8000' ,
            type: 'GET',

Comment: @EdwardBlack, Can you edit the plunker so that I can understand it clearly. It will be a great help. Since I am pretty new to AJAX. Thank you.

Comment: If you decide to use GET don't add password to URL, it's not secure.

Comment: @Fab ok let me try that asap and get back thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your AJAX URL is wrong, you do not need to type in the full address. The Serialize method should do that for you. All you need is `localhost:8000? + data`. And as @zer00ne said, never use a `GET` if your sending in a password, it will show up on the URL. As a rule of thumb, anything sent in a form should be a `POST` request, unless some rare cases which I am not aware of.

My suggestion:

```
$.ajax({

        url: 'http://localhost:8000?',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
```

This way your sending in your information to the proper place and securely.

Answer (score 1):

```
    url: 'http://localhost:8000?userName=&password=&firstName=&lastName=&email=',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
```

become

```
    url: 'http://localhost:8000?' + data,
    type: 'GET',
    //data: data,
```

Comment: since we don't want our password to be visible to anyone like zer00ne said. So I would stick to Leo's solution.